# jQuery simple tabs

Tags: jquery, css

I've created simple tabs with jQuery - hiding and showing the appropriate div onClick.
See example here http://jsfiddle.net/DCNpK/1/
Everything works fine - my question is regarding the functionality below:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
$(activeTab).show();
```

Can anyone explain why does -  `$(activeTab).show();` -  display the correct div even though - `var activeTab` -  refers to the value of the href, and not the id of the div?

Answer (score 4):

Because inside the href there is the string "#div1" which is  jQuery selector so `$("#div1")` gives you the correct div

Answer (score 3):

Check the link given below, this shows a simple tab by comparing the id and data_target attribute:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
var tab_id = $('.tab-content').attr('id');
var datatarget = $(this).attr('data-target');
if ($("#" + datatarget == tab_id)) {
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + datatarget).addClass('current');
   } else {
    alert("no-match");
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmr7835e/